# One-to-two mapping from 3D rotations to the unit quaternions?

Tags: rotations, group-isomorphism, quaternions

Is it true that a 3D rotation is mapped to unique two opposite unit quaternions?

For the zero-angle rotation (identity rotation), there can exist infinite number of unit quaternions.

I'm curious why the set of 3D rotation is isomorphic to 3-sphere and projective 3-space.

Comment: As you've found, the formula that relates a quaternion to a rotation of $\theta$ degrees around an axis $\vec{v}$ collapses when $\theta = 0$, and the result no longer has a dependency on $\vec{v}$ (essentially because of a multiplation by zero)

Comment: First sentence: Yes. Second sentence: no, the zero-angle rotation corresponds to only $\pm1$ in $S^3$. The polar form $\pm\exp(0\cdot{\bf v})$ has infinitely many possible $\bf v$, though. Third sentence: $SO(3)$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb {RP}^3$ but not to $S^3$. See they're the same by seeing they're both $S^3/\Bbb Z_2$.